# Do I need to clone a webform?

Tags: 7, webforms

I have created a webform a few days back. Now I want to re-use the webform which I created earlier with other results, so to save my time and energy I just want to clone that webform and reuse for a different purpose.

Note: previous webform has some result. However I do not want to have this result in the exported webform, I only need the form.

Comment: Do you want to add result too in the exported webform?

Comment: No @vishal i only need the form

Comment: Then check the solution provided by me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [Webform Share](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_share)(https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_share) module to export & import

Example usage 1: Prepopulated webforms

1. Create a webform with the required components.
2. Export the webform
3. Edit the webform content type and paste in the content from the export (under Publishing options)
4. Use the standard node add content links and each new content item created should be prepopulated with the exported webform.

Comment: Great module, lots of time saved :)

Comment: I am trying to use node clone but the 'clone' operation won't show up for any of my 'webform' content types.

Comment: Note that Webform Share doesn't export or import the node body or properties, only the webform-specific data.

Answer (score 3):

[Node clone](https://www.drupal.org/project/node_clone)  module is another option for webform

> The clone module allows users to make a copy of an existing item of site content (a node) and then edit that copy. The authorship is set to the current user, the menu and url aliases are reset, and the words "Clone of" are inserted into the title to remind you that you are not editing the original content.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Node Clone](https://www.drupal.org/project/node_clone) for cloning webforms or any nodes. It provides a simple interface to clone webform or nodes on node page itself.

If you want to export the submission data also then you can use [webform import module](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_import).

Answer (score 0):

If you need the webform configuration of the webform node you can use https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_template

> **Copy webform configuration from one node to another**
>
> This is an add-on
>   module for Webform that allows you to select webform enabled content
>   types as "source" and/or "destination" types. On node edit/creation of
>   the so called "destination" types, you have to option to apply (=
>   copy) the webform settings (including all webform fields) from nodes
>   of the "source" type.

Im note sure about the submissions.